# Connect Lightsail Container that runs NestJS and configures Bull with another Lightsail Container with Redis

Tags: redis, nestjs, amazon-lightsail

I'm doing a server-side application in [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) that configures [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) to connect to Redis for queues. I have followed the official documentation of NestJS for this purpose [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues).

Locally, I have 2 Docker containers, one for the NestJS app and another one for Redis. All is working fine using the host as `localhost` and the port `6379` to establish the connection between them.

My issue starts when I tried to run a Docker container on [Amazon AWS Lightsail Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/lightsail-containers-an-easy-way-to-run-your-containers-in-the-cloud/) with Redis and try to connect to it.

On Amazon AWS Lightsail Containers, I have two containers with this:

1. NestJS app running in production mode.
2. Redis with default settings.

[image]

In the configuration of my Redis container, I have opened the port 6379 over TCP. And in the configuration of my NestJS container, I did the same thing.

All containers on Lightsail have a public domain and a private domain. I have used the private domain as the host to pass to the Bull configuration, example:

```
createSharedConfiguration(): Promise<Bull.QueueOptions> | Bull.QueueOptions {
    return {
      redis: {
        host: my-redis.service.local, // <- Private domain of my Redis container
        port: 6379,
      },
    };
  }
```

When I deploy my NestJS app to its container, I receives the following in the console:

```
(node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/index.js:308:37)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:483:8)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

NestJS seems to try to connect but he can't and I don't know why.

What I am missing?

My goal is to connect my server-side application in one container to another container that has Redis on it. Both containers are on [Amazon AWS Lightsail Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/lightsail-containers-an-easy-way-to-run-your-containers-in-the-cloud/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use container-name as host to connect another container